# How To Get Rid Of Acrobat Ants

Tags: pest-control, pest, ants

Recently my house has been invaded by acrobat ants. They are everywhere. On our tables, in our plates, in our glasses. They tend to be menace and have caused us a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 4):

Ants are constantly seeking food and water to maintain the colony. When an ant locates either in your house it lays down a scent trail with pheromes that the rest of the worker ants use as a freeway into your home. The ideal way to ensure they never invade your home again is to wipe out the Queen and the worker ants. This is accomplished by tracing the ant trail back to the entrance tunnel. Next you set an ant bait along the ant trail. Some brand names are "Grants Ant Stakes" and "Raids Ant Blocks". These baits entice the ants to ingest the 'food' not realizing it is a poison. The ants, not reading the FDA's warning labels on the ant bait package, transport bits of the tainted food back to the nest to feed their fellow ant's. Eventually the toxic food is consumed by the Queen and most of the colony which ultimately collapses. I've used with great success glass cleaner to eradicate on contact scout ants and marching workers. It doesn't contain petroleum or harsh chemicals that are found in insecticidal sprays.

Comment: +1 for "the ants not reading the FDA's warning labels"

Answer (score 3):

I have always had good luck with boric acid powder, it's hard to beat.  It's very inexpensive, sold under various names, sometimes as a roach killer, but it kills most bugs.  It's another thing that kills the whole colony if it's tracked back to the nest.  It's odor free.

[image: http://thumbs1.ebaystatic.com/d/l225/m/m4qqX-C29gn5VaEypDiYDZA.jpg]

It lasts a long time where you sprinkle it.  You can apply the powder on the ground outside your doorways, around where pipes come up under the sink, etc. etc.  You can squirt a bead of it around the whole perimeter of your house at the base of the foundation.

If you don't have pets or kids that will get into it, you can mix a small amount of sugar as bait with the boric acid powder on a piece of paper, leave it out - let the ants find it, track it back to the nest - and they're gone very soon.

I don't trust a lot of the nastier insecticides, but I believe boric acid is very safe.  It's considered safe for use in kitchens, not all insecticides are.  Boric acid can be used as an antiseptic, so I figure a little incidental contact is probably harmless.  You can't believe everything you read on Wikipedia, but: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boric_acid